# how to catch error for navigator.clipboard.writeText

Tags: javascript, html

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText
```

doesn't work on all browsers. I tried the following code. it works and copies on firefox but not on opera, it shows alert that the code is copied but actually, it doesn't copy the link and doesn't show the error prompt. and on the browser console, it shows this error: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Document is not focused.`

so, how can I catch this error to show the link in prompt for the user to copy it manually?

if not possible, what is the most supported way to copy the current link to the clipboard?

```
let shareProjectBtn = document.getElementById("share-project-btn");
function copyCurrentURL() {

navigator.clipboard.writeText(window.location.href);
try {
  if (navigator.clipboard.value !== null) {
    alert("Project's link copied to clipboard");
}
} catch (error) {
  window.prompt("Your browser can't copy the link, please copy this link manually",window.location.href);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Promise.catch()` to handle it. Here's an example grabbed straight from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText):

```js
navigator.clipboard.writeText("<empty clipboard>").then(() => {
  /* clipboard successfully set */
}, () => {
  /* clipboard write failed */
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`navigator.clipboard.writeText` returns a `Promise`, so you can either:

move it into your `try` block and use:
`await navigator.clipboard.writeText(window.location.href)`

or use:

`navigator.clipboard.writeText(window.location.href).catch((err) => window.prompt("Your browser can’t copy the link, …"))`

You can read more about Promises here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise